# Unrecognized arguments error when debugging Python script in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, argparse

I'm trying to debug the following script in VS code:

```
import os
import argparse

def parseArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("-cn", "--cert_names", nargs="+", default=None, help='Provide one or several cert names to be created')
    parser.add_argument('-pw', '--password', action='store_true', help='Provide a password for private keys and certs')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if not args.cert_names:
        print("Please provide one or more cert names")

def main():
    parseArgs()
    print(args.cert_names)
```

This is the launch.json file I'm using:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File and libraries",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode" : false,
            "args": ["-cn cert1 cert2 cert3 cert4"],
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        }
    ]
}
```

After I run the debugger in VS code I get the following message:
create_certs.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -cn cert1 cert2 cert3 cert4

What I want is to pass that list as an argument to the script,
I've also tried with "args": ["--cert_names cert1 cert2 cert3 cert4"], and same result,

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with vsc and launch.json, but maybe try `'args': ['-cn', 'cert1',...]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the args separately, like:

```
"args": ["-cn", "cert1", "cert2", "cert3", "cert4"],
```

otherwise they all get passed as one massive argument.